# Obtain all items in a select2 dropdown list using javascript where data is loaded from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

The example I would like to replicate is this: https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/hpkqxto6/ . I need to load data from the server, form a grouping of them and when selecting one item from one group all other items inside this particular group would become disabled. The difference is that I must load data from the server using an ajax call inside select2, instead of listing the < option > elements inside the select element and form a grouping this way. I have trouble selecting all available items in the dropdown list during the javascript manipulation in order to disable items from the same group (line 29 in the above example fails due to there being no < option > elements in html, instead I think they are loaded later and javascript is not able to find them).

The html part looks as follows:

```
<select class="form-control attributoSelect2" name="attributiSelezionati" id="attributoSelect2" value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati"></select>
```

There are no < option > items inside < select > because the ajax call takes care of populating the list, like this:

```
$('.attributoSelect2').select2({
        placeholder: "Cerca Attributo",
        multiple: true,
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 150,
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Configurazione.Attributi.CercaAttributi())",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    search: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.map(function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.Id,
                            text: item.Descrizione,
                            children: item.Children.map(function (itemC) {
                                return {
                                    id: itemC.Id,
                                    groupid: itemC.GroupId,
                                    text: itemC.Descrizione,
                                };
                            })
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Finally my javascript looks as follows:

```
    $('.attributoSelect2').on("select2:selecting", function (evt, f, g) {
        disableSel2Group(evt, this, true);
    });

    $('.attributoSelect2').on("select2:unselecting", function (evt) {
        disableSel2Group(evt, this, false);
    });



    function disableSel2Group(evt, target, disabled) {
        var selId = evt.params.args.data.id;
        var group = evt.params.args.data.groupid;

        var aaList = $(".attributoSelect2 option");

        $.each(aaList, function (idx, item) {
            var data = $(item).data("data");

            var itemGroupId = data.groupid;
            if (itemGroupId == group && data.id != selId) {
                data.disabled = disabled;
            }
        })
    }
```

The problem is that this line:

```
var aaList = $(".attributoSelect2 option");
```

does not load all the option elements because they are not loaded yet. They would be loaded later on using the ajax call. Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You could trigger `$(".attributoSelect2 option")` later when the data has arrived.. use callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose it might be possible to use a global variable and assign it a value in the processresults method during the ajax call. Do you think this would work?

Comment: yes. That can work.

Comment: I tried accessing the option elements during the proccessResults phase in the ajax call but there is no "Disable" property in the items that are received. These are solely the objects received from ajax and no HTML property are contained inside. Do you know how to access the html properties of these items?

Comment: @Razvan u able to resolve yet?